# Как использовать npm-пакет в браузере?

Tags: javascript, npm

У меня есть npm-пакет и старый легаси-проект, который написан на голом es5 (без использования npm-модулей и сборщиков).

Судя по документации, у пакета нет возможности подключения через тэг script.

Есть ли какой-то способ подружить пакет со старым проектом?

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать про абстрактный сферический пакет в вакууме. Скорее нет, но лучше приведите конкретный пакет и тогда можно будет что-то сказать более предметно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen это пакет mjml (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjml) для создания респонсивных шаблонов email-писем

Comment: Подозреваю что только вручную и очень сложно